# spark scala - convert json string to json struct

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with schema like below

```
 |-- aaa: string (nullable = true)
 |-- bbb: long (nullable = false)
 |-- ccc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ddd: string (nullable = true)
 |-- eee: long (nullable = false)
```

Already i have results in val for the above .

I want to convert the schema as below using spark scala

```
  |ddd:struct (nullable = true)
      |-- aaa: string (nullable = true)
      |-- bbb: string (nullable = true)
      |-- ccc: string (nullable = true)
      |-- eee: string (nullable = true)
```

Please help

Comment: Please show your effort and post your code.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please give a more detailed description of your question. Include code when possible.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [struct function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html)

the first method is to use `withColumn` api and if you don't want the original columns you can `drop` them as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("ddd", struct(col("aaa"), col("bbb").cast(StringType).as("bbb"), col("ccc"), col("eee").cast(StringType).as("eee"))).drop("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "eee")
```

the second way is to use `select` api as

```
df.select(struct(col("aaa"), col("bbb").cast(StringType).as("bbb"), col("ccc"), col("eee").cast(StringType).as("eee")).as("ddd"))
```

Comment: Hi Harsh Thanks for your reply

Comment: But it is appending

Comment: i Have to create a new schema as above

Comment: it does create a new schema :) see my updated answer

Comment: and i am not Harsh @gayathri :P

Comment: oops .sry Ramesh

Comment: U r  a star Ramesh!! It helped . Thanks a lot !!

Comment: hehe :) you can accept the answer if it helped. you can upvote too when you would able. :)